# Set Time Out Code Not working properly

Tags: settimeout

I want to set a timeout and stop a function when my loop finishes.

Here is my code with the set time out function at the bottom.

```
//Drawing the car turning and changing speed
function drawCar() {

var cx = canvas.width/2;
var cy = canvas.height/2;

var totalcars = 2;
var car_distance = 100;

   for (i = 0; i <= totalcars; i++) {
          // Get random positions for stars.
          var x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
          var y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

          if (x1 >= 190 && y1 >= 0) {
          x1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
          y1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);

          context.save();
          context.translate(x1, y1);
          context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
          context.drawImage(car1, -(car1.width / 1), -(car1.height / 1));
          context.restore();
          }
}
if (i == totalcars) {
    return;
}
setTimeout(drawCar, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is used to specify that a function will be *started* some amount of time in the future; what you've written insures that your `drawCar` will always be executed again (after a pause).

If you remove the call to `setTimeout`, your function will stop when the loop finishes.  (And the `if` at the end is pointless: the function will return either way.)

Comment: Hey Scott, i did set time out, but the car keeps flickering randomly i dont want the car to dissapear, or appear on top of each other, If you would like to see it, i have it on Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/zewikarojo/5/edit

Comment: *Don't* call `setTimeout`; that just gets cars drawn *more* often.